# NSNumberformatter quasi Scientific notations

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsnumberformatter

I need the NSNumberFormatter to conditionally display very huge or very small numbers as Scientific notation. But if the number can be presented without, i need it to be only decimal.
6.62e-34 is Ok, but 4,2E1 is not.

Elsewhere in the system, I have solved this using the following method:

```
- (NSString *) formatNumber: (double) d {
    BOOL sci=NO;
    double dd = d;
    if (dd<0.0) dd=(-d); 
    if ((dd>0.0) && (dd<1e-3)) sci=YES;
    if (dd>1e+8) sci=YES;
    if (sci) [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
    else [nf setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle]; 
    return  [nf stringFromNumber:[NSNumber numberWithDouble:d]];
}
```

But at this particular place, the whole thing is set up in the interface builder, with bindings to an managed object modell and using an array controller object. In the first text cell of the colum in the tableview, I have dragged in the numberformatter. I dont know if its possible to define some custom methods to be called to do the formatting, instead of using this NumberFormatter. If I take it away, I got errors when I run it.

anyone have some idea ?

Comment: You can use if-else to check and display accordingly...

Comment: Do you want 6.62e-32 and 421 from a  single NSNumberFormatter ?

Comment: Are you populating your table view using a data source, or are you using bindings?

Comment: I am using bindings to a managed object model, and the NSNumberFormatter is dragged into the text cell of the table, and configured directly in the .xib editor of xcode. The bindings and everything with the array controller is set up here. Elsewhere in the system I am working on I have programmed a solution to this turning scientific modus on and off depending on the value of the number. Here it is no programming, and I dont know where to put in code to go around it.

Comment: to @AnoopVaidya: Yes, it is the numberformatter put into the cell of the table in the .xib editor of Xcode.

Comment: [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g"] does exactly that. Is it not sufficient for you? Possibly with a number of significant digits modifier?

Comment: It is not a problem with the programming, it is when I have set it up in the interface builder as I described. Is it possible do write a custom numberformatter and make it available in the interfacebuilder ? - or can I intercept some messages to overrun the conversation. The reason for not using the C format style as you mentioned @fishinear is that the number formatter have capabilities to configure the use of decimal point and 1000 separator.

Comment: If you need only at one place(for sure) if-else is better. If you need in it more than 2 places Override the numberFormatter and place if-else inside this. RDelmar has done exactly the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is write a subclass of NSValueTransformer. You can then provide the name of that transformer class in IB, in the bindings inspector. Here is an example:

```
@implementation RDTransformer

- (id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        self.formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
        [self.formatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterScientificStyle];
        [self.formatter setMaximumFractionDigits:3];
    }
    return self;
}

+(Class)transformedValueClass {
    return [NSString class];
}

+(BOOL)allowsReverseTransformation {
    return NO;
}

-(id)transformedValue:(NSNumber *)value {
    if ([value compare:@1000] == NSOrderedAscending) {
        return value.stringValue;
    }else{
        return [self.formatter stringFromNumber:value];
    }

}
```

In IB, the column (in a single column table) has its value bound to Array Controller.arrangedObjects with a value transformer of RDTransformer. I don't have any formatters connected to the table cells.